# Array doesn't implement ICollection<T> but is assignable

Tags: c#, arrays, icollection

Look at this insane piece of code:

```
ICollection<int> list = new[] {1, 2, 3};
list.Add(4); // NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size.
```

I'm not wondering about the exception! I'm wondering that a simple array could be assigned to `ICollection<T>`. I see `Array` implements `IList` and `ICollection` but as far as I know it never implements `ICollection<T>`!

Comment: If the linked question/answer isn't enough to cover what you asked, I (or someone else) will reopen the question

Comment: [Arrays automatically implement `IList<T>`](http://tinyurl.com/z3xwlxb) which implements `ICollection<T>`. It's also mentioned in the [`Array` documentation](http://tinyurl.com/363o4u4)  but a bit hidden: _"Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the `Array` class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks. That's the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I see Array implements IList and ICollection but as far as I know it
>   never implements ICollection

It does implement `ICollection<T>`, the implementation is simply injected at run-time.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`,
>   `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. **The
>   implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result,
>   the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the
>   Array class.** In addition, there are no reference topics for interface
>   members that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic
>   interface type (explicit interface implementations). **The key thing to
>   be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that
>   members which add, insert, or remove elements throw
>   NotSupportedException.**

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. But would people do that. That's a ticking time bomb!

Comment: How do you inject a interface at runtime?